# B+ Tree disk implementation

Tags: data-structures, tree, binary-search-tree

I am attempting to write a key-value store in rust, with a b+ tree for indexing. I am creating an index file to store the b+ tree, and a data file to store the values of the leaf nodes. I am splitting the files into constant size blocks on the data file and the index file. Where I am having a problem is in the index file.

What is the best format to store the tree? I am currently storing three item for internal nodes: the index value, the offset (the number of bytes) to its children in the index file and a bit to say whether the current node is a leaf node (which would mean the offset number points to the disk file), with the entire tree serialized as a preorder traversal.

But during insertion it will be very costly when a new level is added to the tree for example, and I will need to rewrite the entire tree (index) to the disk.

Is there any way to optimize / keep track of the new nodes created and only replace those instead of writing the entire tree?

Comment: Yeah, you can't serialize the whole tree as a preorder traversal.  Nodes should be written as blocks of a fixed size, and you should be able to put any node anywhere in the index. Unused blocks should be linked into a list or other structure to keep track of them.

Comment: @MattTimmermans Over time your strategy would lead to lots of defragmentation right? Which means a lot of system calls for cursor `seek` calls will happen, which are very expensive.

Comment: Yes, but that will happen in your case too, since indexes are not accessed in preorder.  SSDs fix most of that problem, but also DBs will try to keep the top levels of the index cached in memory.   Seek latency should be considered in your choice of block size.